# How to integrate 2 different python 3 tkinter GUI programs with different geometry managers

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, grid, pack

Iam new to python. and I'm trying to create a small GUI application using Tkinter in python3.  The functionality that I want to achieve is that

1) the program has to create a small window which takes in a search string from the user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVlL4.png)

2) once the user enters the string and hits the search button, the program has to retrieve data from an excel sheet and show up the results in a Tkinter table (pandas table module).

I have written code separately for both of these functionalities and unable to put them together

here is the code for achieving the functionality 1.

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import pandas as pd

# Instance of class tkinter Tk
root = Tk()
# Icon for the window
root.iconbitmap('D:/icon.ico')
# Window Title
root.title('Tri2Find')

df_in = pd.read_excel('D:/tmp/data.xlsx',index_col = None)
# Input variable for entry string
entry_search_string = StringVar()
# Text Field for search string
entry_search = Entry(root, width = 50,textvariable = 
entry_search_string).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
# Function for different actions of [GO SEARCH!!] Button
def button_entry_search():
    search_string = entry_search_string.get()
    # Create a label when button is clicked and print the search term in the label
    label_entry_search = Label(root, text = "SEARCHING :  "+search_string ).grid(row = 0, column = 2)
    # Creating a list for holding the index values
    index = []
    # Iterating over each row of the data frame
    for i in range(len(df_in.index)):
        # Converting each row of a data frame into a pandas series
        row = pd.Series(df_in.iloc[i,:])
        # Check for the user's search token in each row
        pattern_boolean = row.str.contains(search_string, case = False, na = False)
        # If presence of token is true
        if pattern_boolean.any() == True:
          # Then append the value of i to the index
          index.append(i) # Index contains the row indicies with the required search term
    # Data frame which contains the rows with required search term
    df_out = df_in.iloc[index,:]
    print(df_out)

# [GO SEARCH!!] Button of search term 
button_search = Button(root,text = "GO SEARCH!!", width = 13,command = 
button_entry_search).grid(row = 0)

# loop function to Run and keep the GUI open
root.mainloop()
```

The above code takes in the string and prints the results to the console but not to the tkinter table

Here is the code for functionality 2.

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
import pandas as pd

# Reading the excel from local path
df_in = pd.read_excel('D:/tmp/data.xlsx',index_col = None)
# Reading user input from console
search_token = input("Please Enter the search term :")
# Print a status message
print("Showing results for..." +str(search_token)) 
# Creating a list for holding the index values
index = []
# Iterating over each row of the data frame
for i in range(len(df_in.index)):
    # Converting each row of a data frame into a pandas series
    row = pd.Series(df_in.iloc[i,:])
    # Check for the user's search token in each row
    pattern_boolean = row.str.contains(search_token, case = False, na = False)
    # If presence of token is true
    if pattern_boolean.any() == True:
        # Then append the value of i to the index
        index.append(i) # Index contains the row indicies with the required search term
# Data frame which contains the rows with required search term
df_out = df_in.iloc[index,:]


class results_table(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.main.iconbitmap('D:/icon.ico')
        self.main.title('Tri2Find')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.table=Table(f, dataframe=df_out,showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        self.table.show()
        return

app = results_table() 
#launch the app
app.mainloop()
```

The above code takes input from the console but gives the output to the Tkinter table.

I need help to integrate these 2 pieces of code into a single file.

1. The user enters the search string and hits search
2. Then the data retrieved should show up in the table.

I assume the error is with the geometry manager because iam trying to use pack() and grid() types in a single instance. But I really dont know how to put these 2 pieces of code without any conflict and acheive the functionality. Iam new to OOP concept of python too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding point 1): TL;DR, why so much code. I didn't read through it but it seems a whole lot to read a string off the user. Does it do something else as well?

Why not just use a simpledialog?

```
message = simpledialog.askstring('Tri2Find','Enter text',parent=root)
```

Or if you need to have your own design and/or validation you can build your own dialog inheriting from simpledialog.